# Convert pandas DataFrame into list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
admit   gpa  gre  rank   
0  3.61  380     3  
1  3.67  660     3  
1  3.19  640     4  
0  2.93  520     4
```

Now I want to get a list of rows in pandas like:

```
[[0,3.61,380,3], [1,3.67,660,3], [1,3.19,640,4], [0,2.93,520,4]]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 132):

There is a built in method which would be the fastest method also, calling `tolist` on the `.values` np array:

```
df.values.tolist()

[[0.0, 3.61, 380.0, 3.0],
 [1.0, 3.67, 660.0, 3.0],
 [1.0, 3.19, 640.0, 4.0],
 [0.0, 2.93, 520.0, 4.0]]
```

Answer (score 31):

you can do it like this:

```
map(list, df.values)
```

Comment: I'll add a bit of warning to this answer.  In Python 3, `map()` returns an iterator so the answer there becomes `list(map(list, df.values))` which is overkill since the shorter spelling `df.values.tolist()` exists.  (Another thing to note is that as of pandas 0.24.0 (January 2018), they recommend spelling `df.values` as `df.to_numpy()`, so I suppose it becomes `df.to_numpy().tolist()`. In its favor it does make it explicit that `df.values` gives an unwrapped numpy object and `.tolist()` should be looked up in the numpy docs.)

Answer (score 12):

EDIT: [`as_matrix` is deprecated since version 0.23.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html)

You can use the built in [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values) or [`to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) (recommended option) method on the dataframe:

```
In [8]:
df.to_numpy()

Out[8]:
array([[  0.9,   7. ,   5.2, ...,  13.3,  13.5,   8.9],
   [  0.9,   7. ,   5.2, ...,  13.3,  13.5,   8.9],
   [  0.8,   6.1,   5.4, ...,  15.9,  14.4,   8.6],
   ..., 
   [  0.2,   1.3,   2.3, ...,  16.1,  16.1,  10.8],
   [  0.2,   1.3,   2.4, ...,  16.5,  15.9,  11.4],
   [  0.2,   1.3,   2.4, ...,  16.5,  15.9,  11.4]])
```

If you explicitly want lists and not a numpy array add `.tolist()`:

```
df.to_numpy().tolist()
```

Comment: Note the question asks for a list of lists, so if a multidimensional array isn't good enough adding a `.tolist()` at the end completes it. `df.to_numpy().tolist()`