# Convert one DataFrame row to flat list

Tags: python, pandas

I new to Python and I'm therefore having trouble converting a row in a `DataFrame` into a flat `list`.  To do this I use the following code:

Toy `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
     "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     "b": [9, 8, 7, 6, 5],
     "n": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

My code:

```
df_note = df.loc[df.n == "d", ["a", "b"]].values #convert to array
df_note = df_note.tolist() #convert to nested list
df_note = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, df_note) #convert to flat list
```

To me this code appears to be both gross and inefficient.  The fact that I convert to an `array` before a `list` is what is causing the problem, i.e. the `list` to be nested.  That withstanding, I can not find a means of converting the row directly to a list.  Any advice?

This question is not a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585280/convert-a-row-in-pandas-into-list).  In my case, I want the list to be flat.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You are almost there, actually just use `flatten` instead of `reduce` to unnest the array (instead of unnesting the list), and chain operations to have a one liner:

```
df.loc[df.n == "d", ['a','b']].values.flatten().tolist()
#[4, 6]
```

Comment: A general solution (less specific to the example) is: `df.loc[index, :].values.flatten().tolist()` where `index` is the index of the pandas Dataframe row you want to convert.

Answer (score 31):

You get a nested list because you select a sub data frame.

This takes a row, which can be converted to a list without flattening:

```
df.loc[0, :].values.tolist()
[1, 9, 'a']
```

How about slicing the list:

```
df_note.values.tolist()[0]
[4, 6]
```

The values are stored in an NumPy array. So you do not convert them. Pandas uses a lot of NumPy under the hood. The attribute access `df_note.values` is just a different name for part of the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're explicitly selecting columns `a` and `b` only to get rid of column `n`, which you are solely using to select the wanted row.

In that case, you could also use the `n` column as the index first, using [set_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_index):

```python
>>> dfi = df.set_index('n')
>>> dfi.ix['d'].tolist()
[4, 6]
```

Comment: maybe OP has more columns and want to subset only `a` and `b`, in case the above does not work on a more generic dataframe. (but good approach still)

Comment: You're right, my answer was based on my interpretation of what the OP was trying to do, and thus less generic. I've edited my answer to clarify this.