# Cartesian product of values in each row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe/matrix which is MxJ and looks like this:

```
**dataframe: R**

index   0 1 2 3 ... J #columns, go from 0 to J

0       3 0 5 6 ... #values - first row
1       .........
....................
M
```

and one more matrix/dataframe which is JxJ and its made from 0 and 1, looks as this:

```
**dataframe: K / its symetric**

index   0 1 2 3 ... J #columns, go from 0 to J

0       1 0 1 0 ...
1       0 1 1 1 ...
2       0 1 1 1 ...
       .........
....................
J
```

I need for each row to calculate

```
sum[0 to J](sum[0 to J](K[i,j]*r[i]*r[j])
```

Basically for the first row the concrte example is: `[(3*3)*1]+[(3*0)*0]+[(3*5)*1]+[(3*6)*0]+[(0*0)*1]+[(0*5)*1]+[(0*6)*1]+[(5*5)*1]+[(5*6)*1]`. So the final result should be a 1xM.

I know how to do it with a 3 for loops, pseudo code for it:

```
sum = []
#J - number of columns
#M - number of rows
for m in range(o,M)
  for i in range(0, J):
    for j in range (i,J):
       sum[m] = sum[m] + (a[i] * a[j]) * wi[i,j]
```

But for loops isn't an option, because my data is huge.
Can someone explain me how to do that cartesian product with rows (that part i dont know how to do it) in more pandas way.

Comment: Possible solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the rows to [lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585280/convert-pandas-dataframe-into-list-of-lists) and use the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists):

```
    import itertools
def get_cartesian_product(input_lists):
    lst_out = []
    for element in itertools.product(*input_lists):
            lst_out.append(element)
    return lst_out
```