# Python - Parse a list of string formatted list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I am having problem in parsing list of strings in the below format. This is actually a pandas dataframe:

```
def parse_text_to_list(row):
    print(row) # eval is not working as inner strings are missing the quotes
    return row

df.apply(parse_text_to_list)
```

**output**

```
# printed only one row to simplify the question
['[[str1, str2], [str1, a long text], ..., [strn, strx]]']
```

But Want to convert it to a pure python list like:

```
[["str1", "str2"], ["str1", "a long text"], ... ["strn", "strx"]]
```

@Negative markers - let me know the reason

Comment: add your input dataframe to Q

Comment: @SreeramTP - Can you help more on it?

Comment: If you can add few rows of  input dataframe to your Q as text, sure I can try to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `regular expression` with `literal_eval` to get the list

```py
import re
import ast

l = ['[[str1, str2], [str1, a long text], [strn, strx]]']

output = ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r'([^\[\],\s][^\[\],]+[^\[\],\s])', r'"\1"', l[0]))

print(output)
```

```
[['str1', 'str2'], ['str1', 'a long text'], ['strn', 'strx']]
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks very much. It worked like charm. but wondering whats happening in the regex part. Can you please explain a bit.

Comment: It is checking if anything starting with anything `except` `[ ] space ,` then in between anything `except` `[ ] ,` more than one times and ending with anything `except` `[ ] space ,`

Answer (score 0):

If you want print each row as a list you can use:

```
def parse_text_to_list(row):
    print(row.tolist())
    return row
```

But if you want convert each row to List,you can use directly:

```
df.values.tolist()
```

[This questions is already resolved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585280/convert-pandas-dataframe-into-list-of-lists)

Comment: No, it does not answer my question